How to generate random raster cell values according to the distribution of same values from another raster
In terra I have an existing raster with values range from 1 to 4 in the following proportions.
"1" appears 5 times; "2" 15 times; "3" 20 times; "4" 60 times
I need to create a new raster with a different shape and extent, and randomly assign the same values 1 to 4 in the same proportion of occurrence as the previous raster.
How do I go about populating NEW.RASTER?
r <- rast(ncol=10,nrow=10, vals=1)
> r[6:20] <- 2
> r[21:40]<-3
> r[41:100] <- 4
> r
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
source(s)   : memory
name        : lyr.1 
min value   :     1 
max value   :     4 
> freq(r)
  layer value count
1     1     1     5
2     1     2    15
3     1     3    20
4     1     4    60
> 
> NEW.RASTER <- rast(ncol=15,nrow=350)
> NEW.RASTER
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 350, 15, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 24, 0.5142857  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 


You can obtain a sample equal to the number of pixels in the new raster, containing only the values of interest (1:4), and using the proportion in your original raster as the probability weight. Then you just need to assign them to the new raster.
library(terra)

# Get frequencies and calculate their proportion
df_f <- freq(r) 
tot <- sum(df_f$count)
df_f$prop <- df_f$count/tot
df_f

#  layer value count prop
#1     1     1     5 0.05
#2     1     2    15 0.15
#3     1     3    20 0.20
#4     1     4    60 0.60

# Get number of pixels in the new rasters
npix <- ncell(NEW.RASTER)

# Sample the values of interest
set.seed(8)
vals <- sample(df_f$value, npix, replace = TRUE, prob = df_f$prop)

# Calculate new proportions just to check (they will be closely similar)
df <- as.data.frame(table(vals))
df$prop <- df$Freq/npix
df

#  vals Freq       prop
#1    1  270 0.05142857
#2    2  790 0.15047619
#3    3 1072 0.20419048
#4    4 3118 0.59390476

# Assign the values to the new raster
values(NEW.RASTER)<-vals


Thank you Jonathan - this has worked and brings me great flexibility - much appreciated.   There had also been a reply from @Robert Hijmans which was very useful; it achieved the same yet carried forward proportion of NA values if necessary.   This was as follows
r <- rast(ncol=10,nrow=10, vals=1)
r[1:2] <- NA
r[6:20] <- 2
r[21:40]<-3
r[41:100] <- 4
NEW.RASTER <- rast(ncol=15,nrow=350)
NEW.RASTER <- setValues(NEW.RASTER, sample(values(r)))


 summary(r)
     lyr.1      
 Min.   :1.000  
 1st Qu.:3.000  
 Median :4.000  
 Mean   :3.398  
 3rd Qu.:4.000  
 Max.   :4.000  
 NA's   :2      
> summary(NEW.RASTER)
     lyr.1    
 Min.   :1.0  
 1st Qu.:3.0  
 Median :4.0  
 Mean   :3.4  
 3rd Qu.:4.0  
 Max.   :4.0  
 NA's   :105  

